# .Net Core 2.0 Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to be able to use Azure Ad with OpenIdConnect for the authentication in my application which I managed to make it working.

My problem is that when I use in .NET Core 2.0 the OpenIdConnect Authentication and I use this default Identity:

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

When I try to access controllers that have the [Authorize] attribute **not being logged in already** it redirects me to the azure URL indefinitely.

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The .Net core 2.0 identity should works well with Azure AD authentication via OpenID connect. I also wrote a simple code sample, you can refer it from link below:

[webappLocalAccountAAD](https://github.com/VitorX/webappLocalAccountAAD)

You may share some error message or detailed info which block you so that other community could help to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. The problem is that when you try to access a page that uses the Authorize Attribute in the controller and you are not logged in. It keeps redirecting you to the azure URL indefinitely. In the code example you provided. Try adding the [Authorize] attribute to your About page and try to access it without logging in first.

Comment: This issue is caused by the default login-in page config using the OpenIdConnect, since we have config local account and aad account. After authenticate by Azure Active Directory, the request was not handle correctly. To fix this issue, we can config the use the cookie authentication via `options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;`. And I have updated the code sample, please feel free to let me if it works for you.